# Writing a Date Range in WHERE Clause with 2 Requirements

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple query where I need to look back at past 12 months of data, but starting 7 months ago. This is because I need to put the query into production and not have to go back and edit it 5 months from now. Is it viable to write two separate conditions in the WHERE clause where the first one takes precedence over the next:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE
REPORT_DATE >= '2022-11-01' AND
REPORT_DATE >= DATEADD(month, -12, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

When I run the query now, I get everything from November 2022 to present, but wondering when December 2023 arrives if it will give me past 12 months?

Comment: I might be minded to write that as `REPORT_DATE >= GREATEST('2022-11-01', DATEADD(month, -12, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))` if you are on a version with that function available

Comment: Why not? You can try by changing '2022-11-01 to a year earlier, and see/test for yourself.

Comment: Try it and inspect the execution plan. I suspect you'll see that the query optimizer simplifies this. As far as the query is concerned, `DATEADD(month, -12, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())` is a constant value.

Comment: There won't be any precedence but the where clause will produce expected result. Whether SQL Server will optimize it is another issue.

Comment: The query plan for the `GREATEST` version is potentially more efficient. With the `AND` version it starts the seek at `2022-05-30` (as at today) and then discards everything before `'2022-11-01'` with a residual predicate. Though in 5 months time the '2022-11-01' part becomes irrelevant anyway

Comment: @MartinSmith _potentially_, but they are not that smart at Microsoft, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/_77w3yvQ, which shows two same execution plans.

Comment: @Luuk - those plans aren't the same and confirm what I said. There is a difference between calculating the exact seek point and going there and just choosing one of the seeks and using the other predicate as a residual. `[fiddle_901524d1c730402d8f3a11f629fbc535].[dbo].[dates].[d] >= dateadd(month,(-12),CONVERT(date,getdate(),0))),  WHERE:([fiddle_901524d1c730402d8f3a11f629fbc535].[dbo].[dates].[d]>='2022-11-01'` **is not the same** as `SEEK:([fiddle_901524d1c730402d8f3a11f629fbc535].[dbo].[dates].[d] >= greatest('2022-11-01',dateadd(month,(-12),CONVERT(date,getdate(),0))))`

Comment: Ok, you are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using two date filters works, personally I would pre-process the date logic into a single variable.  That avoids issues with query plans and the nonsense of multiple filters on the same start date.

```
--1 if it's past '2023-11-01' then take the prior 12 months of data.
--2 otherwise it's before '2023-11-01' so take data after '2022-11-01' (currently 7 months ago)
    
    
DECLARE @startDate date = CASE WHEN GETDATE() >= '2023-11-01' 
                           THEN DATEADD(month, -12, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
                           ELSE '2022-11-01'
                          END
    
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE REPORT_DATE >= @startDate
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will work, but I would use an expression that could be computed without looking at each row:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE REPORT_DATE >= CASE
    WHEN DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()) > '20221101' THEN DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()) ELSE '20221101'
END
```

---

Note that I tested your original query in SQL 2012. I noticed that:

- When you have data between (for example) 2013-2023

  - the hard-coded date becomes part of a seek predicate, understandably so
  - the other date becomes part of predicate
- When you have data between (for example) 2022-2032

  - both dates become part of a predicate, and an expensive one...

This is just an observation, not saying that you need to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work.

If you want to feel safer, why not just declare a "virtual" getdate variable:

```
declare @virtual_getdate datetime='20231201'

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE
REPORT_DATE >= '2022-11-01' AND
REPORT_DATE >= DATEADD(month, -12, CONVERT(DATE, @virtual_getdate))
```